# Is there an easy way to multiplex the state of multiple switches in an AC circuit?

Tags: ac, multiplexer, modulation, demodulation

If I had a circuit like this...

[image]
<sub>*Blurple boxes represent unknown devices/circuitry</sub>

What would be the simplest way to transmit the states of the switches, using only a single wire?

In essence I'm trying to control three light bulbs (loads) using three switches, trouble is there's only one conductor (wire) between the switches and the bulbs. So I have to transmit the state of the switches; an undetermined distance (less than 500 ft.), using only a single conductor (wire).

I was thinking either phase modulation or frequency modulation, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement either. I want to make this as simple, and as small as possible. I also want to avoid micro controllers, and other such things.

The idea is that whichever switch is closed, the corresponding lead on the other end will be energized. For example...

[image]
<sup>Contact A Closed</sup>
[image] 
<sup>Contact B Closed</sup>
[image]
<sup>Contacts A and C Closed</sup>
<sub>*Orange in the diagrams represents the flow of electricity.</sub>
<sub>*Blurple boxes represent unknown devices/circuitry</sub>

So the truth table would look like this:

```
A   B   C   |   a   b   c
0   0   0   |   0   0   0
1   0   0   |   1   0   0
0   1   0   |   0   1   0
1   1   0   |   1   1   0
0   0   1   |   0   0   1
1   0   1   |   1   0   1
0   1   1   |   0   1   1
1   1   1   |   1   1   1
```

Comment: I guess after you sum them, maybe switches A, B and C could each implement different filters to extract and isolate the desired signal? Also, I'm not sure your diagram makes sense to me. One AC source and 3 resistors (no frequency dependence there?)

Comment: @dext0rb This is a basic representation of a circuit, which makes it easier to focus on the problem.  In reality, each resistor represents more complex circuitry.

Comment: What is the frequency and bandwidth of the original signals? What sort of thing is the single "link" in the middle? FM is probably workable if you don't mind building and debugging analog electronics.

Comment: (This is essentially how analog cable TV works)

Comment: The diagram is really unclear. If I understand it you want help designing the blue and purple boxes. Which are mux'ing/demux'ing 3 signals. But according to the diagram, the three signals are identical. So why not just send one signal across the link?

Comment: We need more information. Will you need all three signals accessible at one time, to any of the outputs? Will all three signals need to be present on all three outputs? What is the frequency/bandwidth of these signals?

If you only need one signal present at one output at a time then a simple switch matrix can do what you want without the complication of modulating the signals and without too much insertion loss. On the extreme end, a matrix can even be built out of coaxial switches that cover from DC to ~40GHz.

Comment: As the two end blocks are apparently connected by wire, why not just use amplitude modulation, 3 different bands? At the other end, 3 differently tuned simple AM receivers can each be wired to switches via peak detectors. That's all analog, no microcontrollers, and the schematics are easily found on the net for each of these blocks.

Comment: You have three loads so what sort of signal do you need to apply to them ie what voltage and what current. Is it dc or is it ac as per the question. Do the loads have to be fed as if the three individual signals were transmitted on three wires. In short tell us what you want to happen without trying to focus on the method. It seems nobody understands what you're trying to do!

Comment: Your diagram is probably wrong. As ashown A B C are switched in parallel with fixed resistor (unnamed)  It's moire likely you want a series arrangement , but maybe not.
Using just 2 x CD4051 IC's will provide a mux/demux function. Both are steeped / clocked at the same time. It's likey also that as shown the purple mux/demux is unnecessary and can be a piece of wire. As a geeral example it has some value. You should NOT geeralise when your requirement is so unclear. If you start with a simple specific problem you are more likely to get answers that can lead to the next question.

Comment: [CD4051 data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf) also CD405X family. See fig 23 for a mux/demux example.

Comment: Your edit is still unclear, especially the diagrams, but I just might understand your requirements...How similar is this example to your problem? You have three adjacent switches (e.g., a 3-gang light switch), and you want each one to independently turn on/off 1 of 3 adjacent lamps on the other side of your yard. You've already run X number of wires underground to the lamps, and it would be a big hassle to add the additional wires needed to have each switch controlling separate parallel circuits for each lamp. Is this right?  If so, what is your value of X above? 3?

Comment: @Justin Exactly.  Realistically, I have 5-7 switches and lamps.

Comment: @Tester101 -- I suggested a major edit to your question.  I guess suggested edits are only supposed to be minor, so it's been rejected, but please take a look at it here:  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25996 and see if you want to use the circuit diagram.

Comment: @Justin My schematic is exactly accurate, the only items I'm not sure of is what's contained inside the blurple boxes. I'm not sure how to make it any clearer.  I have 3 switches (A, B,and C), and 3 relays (a, b, and c).  When switch `A` is closed, relay `a` should be pulled closed, when switch `B` is closed, relay `b` should be pulled closed, and when switch `C` is closed, relay `c` should be pulled closed. The only problem, is there are only 3 wires between the two locations (ungrounded (hot), grounded (neutral), and one extra).

Comment: The revised question shows that this isn't really AC at all, it's a set of binary control signals. In that case there are various "remote control" ICs available, such as http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1525377.pdf : normally you'd have an IR tx/rx in the middle, but you can just link them directly down the wire.

Comment: @Tester101 -- I think many people, including myself, were initially under the impression that you want to transmit 3 different AC signals (for example, 3 simultaneous audio or radio data streams), not enable/disable AC power. That's what pjc50 means when he says they are only binary control signals (enable/disable being the binary state).  Your edits have cleared this up though, I would say.

Comment: Is it a set of switches connected to relays, or is it really some other signal which genuinely changes direction or varies in magnitude in an important way? Your describing it as AC is confusing the issue and preventing you recieving an answer.

Comment: @pjc50 It's alternating current (AC), not direct current (DC). I'm not sure why that's so confusing?

Comment: Driving a relay coil from AC, even rectified AC is not a good idea as it vibrates at the AC frequency. I accept that the whole thing is operating in an AC environment (110V/240V?) but pretty much any sensible control system is going to involve a local low voltage DC supply.

Comment: @pjc50 That is your opinion, and you are entitled to it. However, it is neither here nor there, as I'm working within the constraints of an existing system and have no control over it.

Comment: See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEEQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Felectronics.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F23971%2Fhow-is-this-possible-3-leds-trick&ei=eYx1Usy5MOKpsAT1oYGQBQ&usg=AFQjCNHDeKPJKOD2lznYJbcyMpUTblC-sQ&sig2=DkvolTJv_jgXDVJ_DJDcMA

Comment: @Tester101 An "AC signal" has a specific meaning in electronics. What you're communicating is not an AC signal, but rather the status of 3 switches.

Comment: Check out X-10:http://www.smarthomeusa.com/info/x10theory

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a DTMF encoder/decoder pair...

Answer (score 0):

If the line connecting the two sides of your circuit can accommodate a much higher bandwidth than is present in your original signals, and if you have an easy way to exchange synchronization-control signals, the easiest approach is to use an N-way switch on the left side and a one-of-N decoder feeding N sample-and-hold circuits on the right.  Have the switch on the left cycle through the inputs while the decoder on the right cycles through the sample-and-hold circuits.  The sample-and-hold outputs will be a bit "jaggy", but if the cycling rate is much higher than any frequencies of interest in the original signal, you should be able to filter the jagginess without degrading the original signal too badly.

Depending upon the nature of your original signals, you may be able to use the above approach even if you don't have a separate channel for synchronization control.  For example, if your input signals are always in the range +/-1 volt but your channel can accept values up to +1.5 volts, you could use the left-side circuit output a long 1.5 volt pulse immediately before outputting the voltage on the first input, and a short 1.5 volt pulse immediately before outputting each of the other voltages.  The right-side circuit could increment reset a counter when it sees a pulse over 1.25 volts, and reset it if the pulse exceeds a certain length.